# Does description attribute of Node can change depending on value of node?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

Example:

Node 1 has value 1 then description attribute is "IS OK".

Node 1 has value 0 then description attribute is "IS NOT OK".

or value of description attribute is always the same no matter what is the value of node?

Comment: Why would you want to change the description attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the description attribute is always the same (if it has a `Write` access it can be modified by a client using the attribute write services) irrespective of the value of the node.

**Description attribute:**
Description Attribute shall explain the meaning of the Node in a localised text

**Value attribute:**
The Value attribute is specific to Variable NodeClass. It holds the most recent value of the Variable that the Server has.

I see that you are learning OPC UA and using open source implementations. Here are some other open source implementations that you might be interested in trying out:

- open62541 – https://open62541.org/certified-sdk.html – C stack | Mozilla License | Embedded ready | TSN ready
- NodeOPCUA – https://node-opcua.github.io/ – NodeJS | MIT License | Cloud ready
- FreeOpcUa – https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua – C++ | LGPL-3.0 License | Python bindings
- UA .NET stack – https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard – RCL License for corporate members of OPC Foundation & GPL 2.0 for others | Standard profile | Web oriented implementation
- Eclipse Milo - https://github.com/eclipse/milo - Java | EPL 2.0

If you are looking for more hands-on information, you can also check out these resources:

- Free documentation: You can look at the open source documentation page: https://open62541.org/doc/current/
- Paid online course: Practical introduction to OPC UA – code walk-through and examples in this course use the open62541 stack: https://opcfoundation.org/products/view/practical-introduction-to-opc-ua-part-i

Answer (score 2):

The `Description` attribute will generally stay the same, though the server is free to modify it as it pleases and as mentioned the client may be allowed to write to it depending on the server's configuration.

What you're probably looking for is the optional `ValueAsText` property that some `VariableNode`s may have, which is used to provided a `LocalizedText` representation of an enumeration value.

`DataTypeNode`s representing enumeration types also have an optional `EnumValues` property that is an array of `EnumValueType`, a structure that describes each enumeration value and its display name and description.

These properties are both detail in OPC UA Part 3.